# Как при запуске программы с++ автоматически делать терминал ввода активным?

Tags: c++, консоль, visual-studio-code

Сейчас при запуске программы приходится дополнительно переключаться на терминал и в нем уже вводить данные. Если они скопипасчены, то часто, на автомате, вставляешь их не в терминал, а в исходный код.
Как сделать так, что бы после запуска программы, терминал автоматически становился активным?

Answer (score 1):

Можно настроить поведение в `tasks.json`. Данный файл лежит в папке `.vscode` и там есть раздел `presentation`, который можно сконфигурировать для автофокуса терминала.

[Документация на английском](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_output-behavior).

В документации можно увидеть параметр `focus`, который по умолчанию `false`.
В вашем `tasks.json` нужно изменить на `true`

```json
{
.....
     "presentation": {
       ......
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus":true
      }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, пока не получилось, хотя сделал как Вы советовали.

Comment: @sergey0474 обновил, попробуйте так, хотя это значение по умолчанию

Comment: К сожалению, опять нет(